# In Gson, how can I replicate what @JsonAdapter does on fields with my own annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, gson

I'm deserializing objects in preparation to put them into a database. What I'd like to do is mark fields with the DB types so that I can make sure they won't cause errors when I try to insert.

I'm imagining creating annotations like `@VarChar(50)` or `@Numeric(5, 2)` that I can put on fields and these will correspond to `TypeAdapter`s that make sure the deserialized values fit.

I tried writing my own version of `JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory`, but I think I've convinced myself that that only operates on `@JsonAdapter` annotations that are placed at the class level.

It looks like I would need to do something like re-write `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` to handle annotations on the field level, but that looks fairly involved and I wanted to make sure there's not an easier way.

In particular, it would be really awesome if there were a way to register annotations that you want to use at the field level to specify a `TypeAdapterFactory`. In particular, the `TypeAdapterFactory` should be able to look at the annotation instance and pull out its values.

Another option would be to add a value to the `JsonAdapter` annotation that would let you pass constructor parameters of some sort to the `TypeAdapter` or `TypeAdapterFactory` so that you're not limited to a default instance of the class you specify.

So, my question is, is there an easier way to do this than creating something like `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` and are the other ideas practical and/or anywhere on the project radar?

Comment: I don't think GSON provides something like that. Do you really need to put these annotations into your DTO classes, or you just want to put deserialized objects directly to the database?

Comment: If I'm going to have to sanitize the values anyway, it makes sense to do the sanitization as part of the deserialization. Otherwise, I have to create a second class that represents the sanitized field values and then I'm basically doing a lot of repeating myself with field lists, etc.